# How to use jooq code generator？

Tags: jooq

I was using jooq3.9.2 when it was found that the code generator was just a layer of pojo's getters method that did not generate setters? I needed to use
Setters and the default constructor, and the generated package name I do not need to have a table, hope that is the same, com.tseng.dao not com.tseng.jooq.table.daos in the code generator how to achieve?

Comment: @Lukas Eder

I see you on GitHub ([#5354] Add <javaBeansGettersAndSetters/> to the code generator to su…) You have submitted some content (setGenerateJavaBeansGettersAndSetters), this function just what I need, I want pojo to generate getters and setters but I used the jooq 3.9.4 when there is no such method?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your code generation configuration?